# Integration of $(a+bx+cx^2)^{-1/2}$ with respect to x in the form of arccosine function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am facing trouble to prove:
$$\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{a+bx+cx^2}}= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-c}}\arccos\left(-\frac{b+2cx}{\sqrt{-\Delta}} \right) \tag{1}\\ \text{when } c<0, \; \Delta=4ac-b^2<0 $$
It's used here: https://youtu.be/O4SIw6cYSow?t=577

But, so far, I have come up with this form:
$$\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{a+bx+cx^2}}= 
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-c}}\arcsin\left(\frac{b+2cx}{\sqrt{-\Delta}} \right)=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-c}}\arccos\left(\frac{b+2cx}{\sqrt{-\Delta}} \right) \tag{2}$$
As you can see, the necessary minus sign isn't appearing inside the inverse cosine function!

By the way, the form with arcsine function is also mentioned in section 2.261 of the book "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products". ([https://www.amazon.com/Table-Integrals-Products-Daniel-Zwillinger/dp/0123849330](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123849330))

TIA

Comment: Maybe you or the YouTube video has made a silly mistake. Mind sharing your steps?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog
I don't think the Youtube video had done any mistake. The formula is used there to derive an equation that was correct. 
Meanwhile, I have got the exact arcsine form as it is mentioned in the book "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products". But the arccosine form isn't matching with the Youtube video's. I will show my steps later. 
Can you please check which one seems correct to you?

Comment: Where is the integration constant?

Comment: **Hint :** What is the relationship between $\arccos(t)$ and $\arccos(-t),$ and how is it connected to your omission of an integration constant ?

Comment: $\arccos{(-t)}=\pi - \arccos{(t)}$.
I just want to derive the equation (1) keeping $\theta_o$ as the integration constant.
Is it wrong? @Lucian

Comment: @Arthur
How should the equations (1) and (2) look like if I wanna keep $\theta_o$ as the integration constant for both of them?

Comment: @raf: There's *nothing* wrong, and *that's* the problem. :-)